# Error building runc from source

Tags: go, containers, runc

I have problem installing runc from source:

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/local/go/bin/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc# make
go build -tags "seccomp" -o runc .
# github.com/seccomp/libseccomp-golang
Godeps/_workspace/src/github.com/seccomp/libseccomp-golang/seccomp.go:25:22: fatal error: seccomp.h: No such file or directory
 // #include <seccomp.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 4):

That looks like [issue 226](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/issues/226):

> this is not an issue.
>   You need `libseccomp-dev` libraries in order to build runc with `seccomp` support. You can still disable this through go build flags.

[PR 220](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/pull/220/files) mentions:

> In order to enable `seccomp` support you will need to install libseccomp on your platform.
>   If you do not with to build `runc` with seccomp support you can add `BUILDTAGS=""` when running `make`.

Comment: sudo make BUILDTAGS="" GOPATH=$GOPATH 
go build -tags "" -o runc .
# github.com/opencontainers/runc
./spec.go:447: cannot use r.Memory.Limit (type *uint64) as type int64 in assignment
./spec.go:456: too many errors
make: *** [all] Error 2